# Step by step Copy from one worksheet to another worksheet in two different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I have two workbooks. They are both open. Book1.xls and Book2.xlsm. In each of those workbooks I have different worksheets:

Book1.xls -> A1, A2, A3

Book2.xlsm -> B1, B2, B3

I want to copy a specific cell range (B5:I29) from Book1.A1 to Book2.B2 (or any other sheets).

I seem to hit a hardwall with the understanding of the syntax and correct procedure to follow.

I tried:

```
' Set paths
FileToCopyFrom = "C:\Book1.xls"  'change path as required
FileToCopyTo = "C:\Book2.xlsm"         'change path as required

' Set Workbooks
Dim workbookToCopyFrom As Workbook
Set workbookToCopyFrom = Workbooks(FileToCopyFrom)
Dim workbookToCopyTo As Workbook
Set workbookToCopyTo = Workbooks(FileToCopyTo)

' Copy+paste
workbookToCopyFrom.sheet("A1")Range("B5:B29, I5:I29").Copy
Worksheets("B1").Range("A10").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

But I am unable to make it happen. Can you please explain me the right procedure to set the workbooks, worksheets, cell range, copy and paste?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of errors.

If the workbooks are opened then simply change

```
Set workbookToCopyFrom = Workbooks(FileToCopyFrom)
```

to

```
Set workbookToCopyFrom = Workbooks("Book1.xls")
```

Similarly for the other

```
Set workbookToCopyTo = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")
```

Also you are missing a `DOT` before the range object and a `S` in the Sheet object.

```
workbookToCopyFrom.sheet("A1")Range("B5:B29, I5:I29").Copy
```

needs to be

```
workbookToCopyFrom.Sheets("A1").Range("B5:B29, I5:I29").Copy
```

Next, your destination is incorrectly coded. I guess you wanted to do this?

```
workbookToCopyFrom.Sheets("A1").Range("B5:B29, I5:I29").Copy
workbookToCopyTo .Sheets("B1").Range("A10").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
```

So your **final code** will look like this

```
Dim workbookToCopyFrom As Workbook
Dim workbookToCopyTo As Workbook

Set workbookToCopyFrom = Workbooks("Book1.xls")

Set workbookToCopyTo = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")

' Copy+paste
workbookToCopyFrom.Sheets("A1").Range("B5:B29, I5:I29").Copy
workbookToCopyTo.Sheets("B1").Range("A10").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
```

Comment: @mehow: you mean number of issues addressed?

Comment: both the simple issues and how to copy between workbooks. Great answer  pointing out all the bads.. One thing I'd personally add would be to actually fetch values from the closed workbook with/out a loop instead of copy-pasting it all as it would have been much faster. If we do not need the formatting etc just values that's the way to go :)

Comment: I get Runtime Error '9': Subsript out of range. I do have both workbooks open. And I copied the path by Shift+right clicking on the file and Copy As Path. So it should be good.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul: The above code is tried and tested. Are you sure you have the names and extensions of the file correct and they are actually opened? Also the names of the worksheets are correct and they exist?

Comment: Yes, I even created two new files (both xlsx) opened them both in the same excel window, copy pasted your code and only changed the paths. I get the error on the Set portion of the code.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul: `and only changed the paths.` You don't paths....See the last part in my answer. That is all the code that you need if the workbooks are opened.

Comment: I need my second cup of coffee. I read that part, and forgot to remove it. Thanks a bunch. it makes more sense now - and it works.

Comment: Yes, it was. Now that the little example works fine, I added it to the code I am working on and I got Run-time error'1004': PasteSpecial method of Range class failed. Any ideas? (I know it is outside the scope of the original question)

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul: There can be many reasons for a pastespecial to fail. What is the new code that you are using?

Comment: Dim workbookToCopyFrom As Workbook
Dim workbookToCopyTo As Workbook
Set workbookToCopyFrom = Workbooks("00 Aggregate.xls")
Set workbookToCopyTo = Workbooks("template.xlsm")
workbookToCopyFrom.Sheets("A1").Range("B5:I29").Copy
    workbookToCopyTo.Sheets("B1").Range("A10").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42881/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-kingsinnersoul)

Comment: I do ot know what happened, but it fixed itself. Thank you